# What is a good repository for Lua modules?

Tags: module, lua, repository

It seems that the greatest disadvantage for Lua when compared to Perl and Python is the relative dearth of modules.

What modules do you think best close this gap?  What is the go-to repository for solid Lua modules?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Lua Rocks](http://luarocks.org) is the most used Lua package management system I think.
For manual downloading etc [LuaForge](http://luaforge.net/) has a whole lot of projects.

Comment: Note that LuaForge is in a bad shape nowadays. If you need a module specific that is not in LuaRocks and is not easily googleable, write to Lua mailing list (or even post a question here, on SO).